# Why does not render? / Aframe with three object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I want to use threejs with aframe.
threejs object does not rendered.

How can I render three object in aframe?

html

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity geometry material id="obje"></a-entity>
  <a-entity camera id="cam"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

js

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

function init() {
  width = document.body.clientWidth;
  height = document.body.clientHeight;

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, width / height);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, +1000);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(400, 400, 400);
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  const entityEl = document.querySelector('#obje');
  entityEl.setObject3D('mesh', box);

  const cam = document.querySelector('#cam');
  cam.setObject3D('camera', camera);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main issues:

1. The presented THREE.js code is redundant. The [camera component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/camera.html#sidebar) already initializes a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` and [geometry](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/geometry.html#sidebar) and [material](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/material.html#sidebar) set a `mesh` on the entity with a `geometry` and a `material`. [See glitch illustrating](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/common-noon-weeder?path=index.html%3A13%3A31)
2. If the built-in components don't provide the functionality you need, you don't have to use them and I recommend encapsulating your code in a [component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html#sidebar). [Glitch illustrating](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hissing-blossom-guarantee?path=box.js%3A5%3A31)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand the relationship between aframe and three.js's object3D.
It's thanks to you.